# Plot horizontal histogram

Tags: pgfplots, histogram

I would want to plot a 2D horizontal histogram, with `ybar interval`, xlabel and x tick label rotate by 45 degrees. I would to put symbolic y coords and fill all white. How can I represent it?

I've tried this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[
    width=15cm,
    height=15cm,
    xbar interval,
    bar width=5pt,
    xmin=0.05,
    xmax=0.2,
    xlabel = Interest,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    symbolic y coords={sport,tennis,basketball,government,aid,charity,catastrophe,epidemic,terrorism,automobile},
    ytick = data,
    % y tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east},
 ]
    \addplot[fill=white] coordinates { 
        (0.15285340939543077,sport) 
        (0.09540517832166039,tennis) 
        (0.08404651315963803,basketball)
        (0.08381236920515132,automobile)
        (0.09480098304371283,government) 
        (0.09153312501031691,aid) 
        (0.08189990416034557,charity) 
        (0.092913400554364,catastrophe) 
        (0.08754789307155249,epidemic)
     };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and I got this result:
[image: result]

Where have I to make any changes?

Regards.

Comment: welcome to tex.se!. for start see 4.5.4 Bar Plots on , page 81 in `pgfplots` manual. then provide complete but small document whit your diagram that we can help you.

Comment: Thank you @Zarko. I've tried to read that paragraph, and I've inserted the result I can obtain in the first message. It's not a good result!

Comment: you should provide complete document :-)! beginning with `\documentclass{...}`  and ending with `\end{document}` in preamble let be only to your diagram relevant packages.

Comment: Why `xbar interval` and not `xbar`? Is it on purpose that you don't have a data point for `terrorism`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to say what you should change, because I'm not entirely sure about what you're after. However, it seems to me that `xbar interval` is the wrong choice here, that `xbar` is better. I changed some other settings as well, see the comments in the code.

If you do want rotated yticklabels, the code you already had works just fine, though I wouldn't use it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[
    width=12cm, % changed size a bit
    height=8cm,
    xbar, % not xbar interval
    bar width=12pt,
    xmin=0, % does it make more sense to start at zero?
    xmax=0.17, % reduced this a bit
    xlabel = Interest,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    enlarge y limits=0.15, % no need to enlarge x limits
    symbolic y coords={sport,tennis,basketball,government,aid,charity,catastrophe,epidemic,terrorism,automobile},
    ytick = data,
%    y tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east}, % I wouldn't use this
    xticklabel style={
      /pgf/number format/fixed % no scientific notation for the smallest values
    }
 ]
    \addplot[fill=white] coordinates { 
        (0.15285340939543077,sport) 
        (0.09540517832166039,tennis) 
        (0.08404651315963803,basketball)
        (0.08381236920515132,automobile)
        (0.09480098304371283,government) 
        (0.09153312501031691,aid) 
        (0.08189990416034557,charity) 
        (0.092913400554364,catastrophe) 
        (0.08754789307155249,epidemic)
     };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mix a lot of things up, that is why you get such a strange result. For details on how to make it better, please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=15cm,
        height=15cm,
        xbar interval,
        bar width=5pt,
        xmin=0.05,
        xmax=0.2,
        xlabel=Interest,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        enlargelimits=0.15,
        symbolic y coords={
            sport,
            tennis,
            basketball,
            government,
            aid,
            charity,
            catastrophe,
            epidemic,
            terrorism,
            automobile,
            dummy,          % <-- needed to prevent an error message (see below)
        },
        ytick=data,
        % y tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east},
        % (just show labels in "fixed" notation)
        xticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
        },
    ]
        \addplot[fill=white] coordinates {
            % resorted entries to match the `symbolic y coords'
            (0.15285340939543077,sport)
            (0.09540517832166039,tennis)
            (0.08404651315963803,basketball)
            (0.09480098304371283,government)
            (0.09153312501031691,aid)
            (0.08189990416034557,charity)
            (0.092913400554364,catastrophe)
            (0.08754789307155249,epidemic)
            (0,terrorism)   % <-- added, so bars all have the same width
            (0.08381236920515132,automobile)
            (0,dummy)       % <-- added, so also the last bar is drawn
         };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]